# bs4 only prints out 1/4 of the contents in the spreadsheet

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

here's the code, I'm trying to parse a spreadsheet whit over 2000 items but when ever I run this script I only get the last one hundred or so what could I do to fix this I have tried different parsers, and I haven't found any solution's

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://backpack.tf/spreadsheet"

sourse = requests.get("https://backpack.tf/spreadsheet").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(sourse, "html.parser")

try:
    for name in soup.find_all("tr"):
        header = name.text
        print(header)


except:
    pass
```

coulden't get the html to work sorry so pls go to https://backpack.tf/spreadsheet

Comment: Except:pass is a bad programming pattern. If you print out the error, you'd be able to understand what's going on. It should never be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to read the table from this page is with `pd.read_html`:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://backpack.tf/spreadsheet"

r = requests.get(
    url,
    headers={
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0"
    },
)

df = pd.read_html(r.text)[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                Name       Type          Genuine          Vintage           Unique          Strange          Haunted     Collector's
0                                                 A Brush with Death   Cosmetic              NaN              NaN    5.11–5.22 ref        18.4 keys              NaN        200 keys
1                                           A Color Similar to Slate       Tool              NaN              NaN  33.11–33.22 ref              NaN              NaN             NaN
2                           A Color Similar to Slate (Non-Craftable)       Tool              NaN              NaN           30 ref              NaN              NaN             NaN

...

2851                               Zepheniah's Greed (Non-Craftable)       Tool              NaN              NaN           12 ref              NaN              NaN             NaN
2852                                      Zipperface (Non-Craftable)   Cosmetic              NaN              NaN        10.55 ref              NaN              NaN             NaN
2853                                                      Zipperface   Cosmetic              NaN              NaN        1.65 keys              NaN     13–14.66 ref             NaN
```